# CMake project with flex/bison

Tags: c++, cmake, include, bison, flex-lexer

I'm working on an hobby project in C++, using `flex` and `bison`. I'm using CMake as my build system, and I had struggle in making all work together.

I'm quite new to CMake so the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindFLEX.html) seems quite minimal to me. It is showed how to link everything in one executable.
But I'm trying to keep all the parts of my code separated, so I would like to have my `flex`/`bison` file in a subfolder. My structure is this:

```
.
├── build
|   └-- ...
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── flexbison
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── lexer.ll
│   └── parser.yy
├── lib
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── ...
├── main.cpp
└── run.sh
```

So I want to have my `yyparse` function separate from my `main.cpp`, as well as my other C++ files. I managed to get it done in this way:

- `project_root/CMakeLists.txt`:

```bash
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

# set the project name
project(progetto-di-prova VERSION 0.1)

add_subdirectory(flexbison)

add_executable(executable main.cpp)

target_include_directories(executable PUBLIC
  "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}"
  "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/flexbison"
  )


set_target_properties(executable PROPERTIES CXX_STANDARD 11)

target_link_libraries(executable parserlib)

set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)
```

- `flexbison/CMakeLists.txt`:

```bash
find_package(FLEX)
find_package(BISON)

flex_target(lexer lexer.ll "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lexer.cpp")
bison_target(parser parser.yy ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/parser.cpp
  DEFINES_FILE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/parser.h)

add_flex_bison_dependency(lexer parser)

add_library(parserlib STATIC
  ${FLEX_lexer_OUTPUTS}
  ${BISON_parser_OUTPUTS}
)
```

- the `main.cpp` file:

```c++
#include <parser.h>     //  <-this was the line causing troule
#include <iostream>

extern int yylex(void);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  yyparse();
  return 0;
}
```

Now, the point is: **is this the correct way of doing so**? Is it better to put the `main` function in the `bison` code?

My main problem, as highlighted in the code, was to include the `parser.h` header file in the `main.cpp`. **Is this the CMake-way to do it**?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ***Is this the CMake-way to do it?*** Your approach looks mostly correct. You could add a `target_include_directories(parserlib PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})`  after your `add_library( ...` to have the include folder automatically when you link to the parserlib target.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would have:

`flexbison/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
...
add_library(parserlib STATIC
  ${FLEX_lexer_OUTPUTS}
  ${BISON_parser_OUTPUTS}
)
target_include_directories(parserlib PUBLIC 
  $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}>
  $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}>
  $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include/parserlib> # <prefix>/include/parserlib
)
```

note: `$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include/parserlib>` need to be adapted if you want and how you install parserlib...

`project_root/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
...
target_include_directories(executable PUBLIC
  $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}>)
...
```

Since `executable` is "target_link" against `parserlib` which provides public include directories, you don't need to list these directories anymore in `executable`'s include dirs.

ref: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html